# How to Cluster Multidimentional and Unkown Data using KMeans?

Tags: python, machine-learning, cluster-analysis, k-means

I have two questions regarding Kmeans Clustering using Python.

I have an auto-generated data called Mystery.npy and its shape is (30309, 784). I am trying to apply the KMeans clustering on it but, I am getting the following error:

```
valueerror: the truth value of an array with more than one element is ambiguous. use a.any() or a.all()
```

Do you have any idea how to overcome this error, or how to cluster such data with KMeans method?

The second question, Is there a certain code to know the type of data that I have?

Your assistance is highly appreciated. 
Thanks,

Comment: The task is to cluster the data and visualize the data including assigned cluster labels. The data can be found here: https://drive.google.com/open?id=1Fkloi7js4Fsji0pWN6Bmn5LgPXI64egm

Comment: pls add a snipchat of your data, i cannot open this link

Comment: and add some code to it, where does the error occure

Answer (score 4, accepted):

@Nael Alsaleh, you can run K-Means the following way:

```
from sklearn.cluster import KMeans
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

X=np.load('Mistery.npy')

wx = []
for i in range(1, 11):
    kmeans = KMeans(n_clusters = i, random_state = 0)
    kmeans.fit(X)
    wx.append(kmeans.inertia_)
plt.plot(range(1, 11), wx)
plt.xlabel('Number of clusters')
plt.ylabel('Variance Explained')
plt.show()
```

[image: Variance Explained by # of Clusters]

Note that `X` is a numpy array. This code will create the elbow curve, where you can select the perfect number of clusters, in this case, 5-6.

If you are working with numpy, you will have an array:

```
array([0.86992608, 0.11252552, 0.25573737, ..., 0.32652233, 0.14927118,
        0.1662449 ])
```

You may also be working with a list,

```
[0.86992608, 0.11252552, 0.25573737, ..., 0.32652233, 0.14927118,
        0.1662449 ]
```

that you will need to convert to `array`: `np.array(X)`, or even a `Pandas` Dataframe:

[image]

You can check column types in a `Pandas` Dataframe by doing:

```
import pandas as pd
pd.DataFrame(X).dtypes
```

In `numpy`, `x.dtype`

After converting data to an array, run:

```
n=5
kmeans=KMeans(n_clusters=n, random_state=20).fit(X)
labels_of_clusters = kmeans.fit_predict(X)
```

This will get you the number of the cluster class that each example belongs.

```
array([1, 4, 0, 0, 4, 1, 4, 0, 2, 0, 0, 4, 3, 1, 4, 2, 2, 3, 0, 1, 1, 0,
       4, 4, 2, 0, 3, 0, 3, 1, 1, 2, 1, 0, 2, 4, 0, 3, 2, 1, 1, 2, 2, 2,
       2, 0, 0, 4, 1, 3, 1, 0, 1, 4, 1, 0, 0, 0, 2, 0, 1, 2, 2, 1, 2, 2,
       0, 4, 4, 4, 4, 3, 1, 2, 1, 2, 2, 1, 1, 3, 4, 3, 3, 1, 0, 1, 2, 2,
       1, 2, 3, 1, 3, 3, 4, 2, 2, 0, 2, 1, 3, 4, 2, 0, 2, 1, 3, 3, 3, 4,
       3, 1, 4, 4, 4, 2, 0, 3, 2, 0, 1, 2, 2, 0, 3, 1, 1, 1, 4, 0, 2, 2,
       0, 0, 1, 1, 0, 3, 0, 2, 2, 1, 2, 2, 4, 0, 1, 0, 3, 1, 4, 4, 0, 4,
       1, 2, 0, 2, 4, 0, 1, 2, 3, 1, 1, 0, 3, 2, 4, 0, 1, 3, 1, 2, 4, 3,
       1, 1, 2, 0, 0, 2, 3, 1, 3, 4, 1, 2, 2, 0, 2, 1, 4, 3, 1, 0, 3, 2,
       4, 1, 4, 1, 4, 4, 0, 4, 4, 3, 1, 3, 4, 0, 4, 2, 1, 1, 3, 4, 0, 4,
       4, 4, 4, 2, 4, 2, 3, 4, 3, 3, 1, 1, 4, 2, 3, 0, 2, 4])
```

To visualize:

```
from sklearn.datasets.samples_generator import make_blobs
X, y_true = make_blobs(n_samples=200, centers=4,
                       cluster_std=0.60, random_state=0)

kmeans = KMeans(n_clusters=4, random_state=0).fit(X)
cc=kmeans.fit_predict(X)

plt.scatter(X[:, 0], X[:, 1], c=cc, s=50, cmap='viridis')
```

[image: K-Means]

Answer (score 1):

What you want to do can be done using *scikit-learns* KMeans module, here is a working example using your data:

```
import numpy as np
from sklearn.cluster import KMeans
# loading your data from .npy-file
mystery = np.load('mystery.npy')
# n_clusters is a hyperparameter set by you
kmeans = KMeans(n_clusters=42, n_jobs=-1).fit(mystery[:1000])
pred = kmeans.predict(mystery[1000:1200])
print(pred)
array([36, 16, 21, 15, 15,  0,  5,  7, 31, 33, 10, 14,  1, 36, 30, 22, 12,
        1, 35, 12, 16, 12, 28, 14, 13, 15,  2, 21, 36,  7,  7,  4, 39,  4,
        4, 18,  5, 31, 17,  2,  2, 26, 38, 34, 34, 36, 13, 13, 26,  1, 26,
        8, 38,  0, 38, 34,  0, 21, 36, 12, 16, 38, 23, 15,  0,  6, 34,  0,
       19,  7,  8, 21, 16, 36, 24,  0,  4, 22, 33, 21, 12, 12,  2, 10, 23,
        2,  3,  0, 12,  0, 24, 21, 12, 33,  4, 14, 34, 10, 21,  0, 33, 26,
       36,  2, 12, 34, 29, 27, 33,  3, 12, 12, 15, 39, 34, 26, 26, 16,  8,
        2, 12,  0, 21, 15, 40, 16, 38, 22, 26, 36, 17,  3, 12,  3, 23, 39,
       34, 36, 33, 38, 15, 21,  7, 34, 23, 33, 34, 33, 26, 34, 26, 30, 16,
        2,  3,  0, 33, 34, 39, 12,  5, 34, 26, 33, 30, 39, 12,  2, 15, 29,
       12, 38, 36, 10, 36, 28,  1, 19, 12, 17, 32, 35, 11, 16, 28, 18, 14,
       15, 31, 34, 19,  0, 17, 12, 11, 39, 18, 26, 31,  0], dtype=int32)
```

If you want to use the full data set, `kmeans.fit(mystery)` may take some time, for testing purposes I used only the first 1000 instances and predicted the foloowing 200 instances.